# ¿Como mostrar una imgen en un ListView que esta en la BD tipo longblob?

Tags: java, android-studio

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto de la universidad, el cual ya tengo realizado el registro tanto como nombre y imagen en la base de datos desde android studio , la imagen se guarda como tipo longblob, estoy trabajando con un servidor  remoto el cual tengo ahí subidas las imágenes y de ahí se guardan al la base de datos, el detalle que tengo que no se muestra la imagen cuando la cargo a la lista, o sera mas conveniente guardarlo como tipo varchar o tipo tex.

**class EstadoMexico**

```
public class EstadoMexico {

private int idmexico;
private String imagenMexico;
private String nombre;

public EstadoMexico (){

}


public int getIdmexico() {
    return idmexico;
}

public void setIdmexico(int idmexico) {
    this.idmexico = idmexico;
}

public String getImagenMexico() {
    return imagenMexico;
}

public void setImagenMexico(String imagenMexico) {
    this.imagenMexico = imagenMexico;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
}
```

**Adapter**

```
public class AdapterUbicacionMex extends ArrayAdapter<EstadoMexico> {

Context context;
List<EstadoMexico> ubicacionList;
List<EstadoMexico> listaOriginal;

public AdapterUbicacionMex(@NonNull Context context,List<EstadoMexico> ubicacionList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_ubicamexico,ubicacionList);
    this.context = context;
    this.ubicacionList = ubicacionList;

    this.listaOriginal = new ArrayList<>();
    listaOriginal.addAll(ubicacionList);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View vista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_ubicamexico,null, true);

    TextView TVNombre = vista.findViewById(R.id.nombre_ubicacion);
    ImageView IMImagen = vista.findViewById(R.id.imagenViewUbicacion);

    TVNombre.setText(ubicacionList.get(position).getNombre());
    IMImagen.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(ubicacionList.get(position).getImagenMexico()));

    return vista;
  }
  }
```

**registroUbicacion.php**

```
?php

   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
   include('conexion.php');

   $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
   $imagen = $_POST["imagenMexico"];

   $path = "uploads/$nombre.png";

   $actualpath ="https://upstream-responses.000webhostapp.com/ImagenConNombre/$path";

   $query = "INSERT INTO t_imagen_estado_mexico(nombre,imagenMexico)
    VALUES('$actualpath','$nombre')";

    $result = $mysql->query($query);

   if ($result) {
   file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($imagen));
   echo "1";

  } else {
   echo "2";
  }
  $mysql->close();
 }
 ?>
```

**ListaUbicacion.php**

```
<?php 
  include('conexion.php');

  $result = array();
  $result['t_imagen_estado_mexico'] = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM t_imagen_estado_mexico";
  $response = $mysql->query ($sql);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response)) {
  $index['nombre']                 = $row['1'];
  $index['imagenMexico']           = $row['2'];

  array_push($result['t_imagen_estado_mexico'],$index);

 }

 $result["success"]="1";
 echo json_encode($result);
 $mysql->close();
?>
```

**ListView**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo ideal es que no guardes la imagen, en vez de eso puedes almacenar su ruta y llamarla a través de ahí.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo te refieres trabajar con librerías como Glide o Picasso y traer la url